# get the content of matched element

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have a string

```
$str = "this is [start] my string [end] at this moment";
```

i need to get the content within `[start]` and `[end]`.

when i use

```
$result = preg_match('/\[start\].+\[end\]/',$str, $m);
```

it mutches `[start] my string [end]`, but i need  to get only `my string`(without spaces).

sure i can make another preg_replace and delete them, but i think there must be more elegant solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use captured groups.

```
$result = preg_match('/\[start\](.+)\[end\]/',$str, $m);
$matched = $m[1];
```

(Note that your regex will fail if there are multiple `[start]`/`[end]` groups (needs lazy quantifier `.+?`), or nested `[start]`/`[end]` groups (use recursive pattern).)

---

If you don't want the spaces, you could avoid matching it in the regex:

```
$result = preg_match('/\[start\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[end\]/',$str, $m);
$matched = $m[1];
```

or just call `trim()`.

```
$result = preg_match('/\[start\](.+)\[end\]/',$str, $m);
$matched = trim($m[1]);
```